# check_procs configuration on server and client

Tags: nagios

I have one Nagios monitoring server and mongo db installed on one server, Solr installed on one server and mysql installed on another server. Each database is included in their respective nagios groups however I have to put a check in nagios for particular process like whether mongo process is still alive or killed etc.

So how do I configure check_procs in Nagios on server as well as client machine

Comment: please let me know any config details of servers are required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the [NRPE](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe) agent on the remote machine. That allows Nagios to execute plugins remotely. The plugin itself has documentation if you run:

```
./check_procs -h
```

Otherwise, what I use to check if the process is running is:

```
/path/to/check_procs -c 1: -C crond
```

You can specify a min/max acceptable range for any process.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. However I have some more questions in mind.

How command defined in commands.cfg gets its values like $ARG1 $ARG2 etc from remote host.

How can I set custom script to check processes on remote hosts.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to just define your check command with the args that you want on the remote host in the nrpre.cfg. Take a look at the original NRPE doc for more info. It's a little out of date on the versions, but if gives all of the steps you need to complete to get it running. http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf